# Finding shortest subsegments from a sentence

Tags: c

**Problem at hand is**: Print first shortest sub-segment that contains given k words , ignore special characters, numbers and case. If no subsegment is found, it should return “NO SUBSEGMENT FOUND”

**Sample Input :**

```
This is a test. This is a programming test. This is a programming test in any language.
4
this
a
test
programming
```

**Sample Output :**

```
a programming test This
```

My 8 test cases are passing but 2 are not.
I'm not getting what's wrong.

I am also looking for more/better testcases.

My code is here in C:

```
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 200000

    int main() {

      char S[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]; // original string
      char *smallCapsStr,*tempStr; //temp strings having only blank space and small letters

      int i=0 ;  // used in for loop as inc variable 

      int start, tail,start2=0,tail2=0; // used in storing start and end index "for answer"

      int total;  // total words to find in substring
      char **arr; // array to store words to find
      char **temparr ; // temp arr to store words
      int ptr[16];

      char *temp2; // temp string
        int z=0; // variable informing the end of string
        int val=0; //counter var
         int x=0; //variable informing the start of string
      smallCapsStr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*200000);
      char c;

    //geting string and converting into small caps
      do {
        c=getchar();
        if((c>='A' && c <='Z')||(c>='a' && c<='z')){
            S[i]=(char)c;
            *(smallCapsStr + i)=tolower(c);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            if(S[i-1]!=' ' && i!=0){
                S[i]=' ';
                *(smallCapsStr + i)=' ';
                i++;
            }
        }

      } while (c != '\n');


      S[i]='\0';
     *(smallCapsStr + i) ='\0';

      scanf("%d",&total);

        arr = (char ** )malloc(sizeof(char*)*total);
        temparr = (char ** )malloc(sizeof(char*)*total);

    // getting words to find in arr and temparr
      for(i=0;i<total;i++){
        arr[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*14);
        temparr[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*14);

        scanf("%s",ptr);
        strcpy(arr[i],ptr);
        strcpy(temparr[i],ptr);
      }

      tempStr=smallCapsStr;

      while(*(tempStr+1)!='\0'){

        sscanf(tempStr,"%s",ptr);

        for(i=0;i<total;i++){
            if(strcmp(ptr,temparr[i]) == 0){

                if(x==0){
                    start = strlen(S)-strlen(tempStr) ;
                    temp2 = tempStr+strlen(ptr)+1;
                }

            x++;
            temparr[i]="";
            break;
            }
        }
        // updating temp string
        tempStr=tempStr+strlen(ptr)+1;
        //if all words are found
        if(x == total){
            tail = strlen(S)-strlen(tempStr) -1;
            x=0;
            val++;
        if(z == 0 || ((tail2-start2)>(tail-start)) ){
            start2 = start;
            tail2 = tail;
        }
        z++;
        for(i=0;i<total;i++){
            temparr[i]= arr[i];
        }
        tempStr=temp2;
        if(val==70)
            break;
        }
      }

    // putting ans
      if(start2 ==0 && tail2 ==0){
        printf("NO SUBSEGMENT FOUND");
      }
      else{
        for(i=start2 ; i<=tail2;i++){
            printf("%c",S[i]);
         }
        }

    free(temparr);
    free(arr);
    free(smallCapsStr);

    }
```

This is a question from amazon.interviewstreets in which testcases are not visible to the user. 
Any sort of help would be good.

Comment: List the failing testcases. That will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: better. List the specifications.

Comment: @UmNyobe - my own's all test cases are passing but dont know why on amazon.interviewstreets 2 testcass "6th and 7th "are not passing..

Comment: Try the below input.... `aksdhaksjhk ^&*( 123 c z 3 aksdhaksjhk aksdhaksjhk z` Your code is returning no subsegment found....